# iframe resizer doesn't work / source page doesn't even scroll

Tags: javascript, iframe

My problem is, that I want this page - ***** as iframe with dynamic height in this page http://www.*****/.

First page is some eshop system that does support including your own javascript. Second is page running on Joomla, I have FTP and admin access to that page.

Problem is, that when I tried iframe-resizer, nothing happened. I included `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js` through javascript

```
document.getElementById("myxcomponent1").innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*****/iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js'></script>";
```

into source page and second file into html of host page.

Problem is propably in first page, because it doesnt even scroll here

```
<iframe src="http://*****/"></iframe>

iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 1349px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JmwTf/96/

Any idea what is the problem? Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: Problem solved, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is all ok, your issue in parent height, so if in your jsfiddle you will add:

```
body{
    height:100%;    
}
html{
    height:100%;
}
```

it will work, but in your own code in your site, check all your parents for this iframe, if they have height 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the issue is that your loading the JS in the iFrame after the page ready event has fired, so when the host page calls the child, the child JS isn't their ready waiting to be called.